# NDVI in ENVI: Output format issue

Tags: classification, envi, ndvi

I am working on NDVI in ENVI... the output file is in Envi Standard format... I required it in Envi Classification format, which can be done through Envi Edit Header tool... This requirement is for its use in Confusion Matrix using Ground Truth Image... but when i performed this, the resulted NDVI image transformed into BLACK color showing as 'unclassified OR class1' portion (what ever name was suggested at the time of conversion into classification format). (As by the editing header, from standard format to classification, it require at-least 2 classes). I need this to perform Tasseled Cap comparison with NDVI.

---

I was not given the option to change the format of output... either integer or other way... It only give this error when i tried to change the output format from Envi Standard to Envi Classification by Edit Header tool.

---

This error is due to heavy file size... most of the time as a glitch in ENVI outputs.
Although the process runs smoothly with "ENVI Edit Header" tool... it automatically changes the output into Classification format with as many classess as defined by the user.

Answer (score 2):

I would need more information to confirm this, but it is possible that you might be saving in an improper numerical format. NDVI is fractional, so if you were saving in at an `integer` level, all of those values would be rounded up or down, possibly turning the screen black. Try running it using a `double` format.